# c++: why does foo(X&) get called instead of foo(X&&)?

Tags: c++, rvalue

Here, creator() returns a pointer to X, which I dereference and pass to foo. Since that's an rvalue, move semantics should be used, right? But when I run it, I find that foo(X&) is called.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct X {
        int i;
};

void foo(X& x) {
        cout << "foo(X&)" << endl;
}

void foo(X&& x) {
        cout << "foo(X&&)" << endl;
}

struct X* creator() {
        return new X {5};
}

main() {
        X x{5};
        foo(*creator()); // prints foo(X&)
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_indirection_operator

Answer (score 3):

`creator()` returns a pointer.

Dereferencing that pointer gets you an lvalue. Pointer dereference results in an lvalue. After all, if `p` is a pointer, you can assign to it: `*p=some_value`, and you can only assign to an lvalue, therefore it has to be an lvalue.

You are getting confused by two things. It is true that the function returns an rvalue. But you're not passing what the function returns. The function returns a pointer, and you are dereferencing the pointer, which results in an lvalue.

Comment: *"and you can only assign to an lvalue, therefore it has to be an lvalue"* -- This is not true of class types.

Comment: @ben itym badly written non-pseudo-reference class types.

Comment: @Yakk: Not sure what you mean. But I mean class types in general. And most class types specifically, in fact. Such as the one in the question.

Comment: @ben most well written class types should `foo& operator(foo const&)&&=delete;`.  I am aware `std` fails.

Comment: @Yakk: Seems like a waste of time to me. But to each his own.

Answer (score 3):

It's helpful to think of things in terms of identity and movability:

- Has identity and cannot be moved from? lvalue
- Has identity and can be moved from? xvalue
- No identity? prvalue

Dereferencing a pointer yields an expression that has an identity, that cannot be moved from, so it's an lvalue. Hence, it matches the `X&` overload.

If you want to call the other overload, you will have to annotate the expression to indicate that it's safe to be moved from. This is what `std::move` is for. Once you do that, the expression becomes an xvalue and now matches the `X&&` overload.